# Powder and RVM Bundler : GemNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I have a rails app running with rvm(1.21) and pow(0.2.0).

I recently had to uninstall/reinstall my app and surprisingly the app has now an error :

```
Your Rack app raised an exception when Pow tried to run it.
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources
~/.rvm/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92
...
```

I googled and stackoverflowed it and did some actions :

- gem install rake/bundle update rake : https://stackoverflow.com/questi...the-sources-bundlergemnotfound
- added pow/rvm rule : rvm env -- [ruby]@[gemset] > .powenv like this : http://ryandeussing.com/blog/20...vm-play-nice-dot-rvmrc-powenv/
- tried to add this .powrc file config : https://gist.github.com/nbibler/5307941
- tried to downgrade rvm to 1.9.2
- recreated symlinks in .pow/
- tested rackup -p 3000 (and as a result localhost:3000 working well)

but with all of these, I always have this error. I couldn't match any other solution to help me test it. Do you have any other idea to make it working ?

Versions :

- RVM 1.21 then 1.9.2 then rvm get head (so 1.22)
- Rails : 3.2.13
- Ruby: 2.0.0 p247
- powder : 0.2.0

I'm on a Mac OS X Lion (migrated from Snow Leopard)

Any idea ?

---

UPDATE :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

  gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
  gem 'rmagick', '2.13.2'
  gem 'carrierwave', '0.8.0'
  gem "localeapp", '0.6.9'
  gem 'globalize3', '0.3.0'
  gem 'strong_parameters', '0.2.0'
  gem 'devise', '2.2.4'
  gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 1.1.0'
  gem "therubyracer", "0.11.4"
  gem "jbuilder", "1.4.1"
  gem "angular-rails", "0.0.12"
  gem "jquery-ui-rails", "4.0.2"
  gem "font-awesome-rails", "3.1.1.2"
  gem "fog", "1.3.1"
  gem "underscore-rails", "1.4.4"
  gem "rake", "10.0.4"

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :assets do
   gem 'uglifier', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'mocha', '0.13.3', require: false
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
  gem 'minitest', '4.7.1'
  gem 'simplecov', '0.7.1', require: false
end

group :development do
  gem 'magic_encoding', '0.0.2'
  gem 'quiet_assets', '1.0.2'
end
```

Comment: look at your error `undler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources` ...............`rake-10.0.4` do you have rake please install it or in Gemfile just `gem 'rake', '10.0.4'` and then `bundle install`

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I didn't mention it : I have rake (10.1.0, 10.0.4). I also tested on different gemsets but all have both versions of rake

Comment: oh...in your gem file you have to mention or lock gem of rake in 10.0.4 version so please change your gemfile and write `gem 'rake', '10.0.4'` and then `bundle install`

Comment: Great ! Anyhow I didn't have the version on my machine. I don't know why it was mention on bundle install :/ I did also a `gem install rake -v 10.0.4`, then `bundle update rake`  Anyway, I tried to stop/restart powder and it shows always the same error message

Comment: please `rm Gemfile.lock` then mention `gem 'rake', '10.0.4'` in Gemfile then `bundle install` ...just three simple step hope it will work

Comment: please post your gemfile.

Comment: Grrrrrr. I did the 3 steps as you mentionned but always the same (should I reinstall something ?). The `bundle list` output is rake 10.0.4 but I still have the message. (Note that `gem list` outputs "rake (10.1.0, 10.0.4)

Comment: Ok I tried today to delete all gemsets, gemfile.lock, and both .powenv and .powrc, uninstall powder and reinstall it. At the end, I created a fresh .powrc file and bundle install ... and I'm always stuck in it ... :( But why is the file calling gemset @global as I have only default gemset remaining ?

Comment: Continuing investigations. I try to reinstall a ruby 1.9.3 version because on another mac, the app runs perfectly with this version.

Comment: Is there something ( a code line, somewhere) that could force using a wrong path such as : `~/.rvm/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. We fixed the issue. The only solution we had was to drop DB, kill all pow and PG processes and restart all servers.

Seems there was a mess between what the server wanted and what the app proposed.